# What movie is this avocado-like monster from?

Tags: story-identification, movie

[image: squat brown toad-like being with hands]

Dark color body, no neck, short arms legs, weird face

Comment: Where did you come across a picture of Chet cropped from his movie?

Answer (score 32):

That is a picture of Chet (Bill Paxton) from [*Weird Science*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090305/) after Lisa (Kelly LeBrock) has transformed him in revenge for how Chet has treated his younger brother Wyatt (Ilan Mitchell-Smith).

Here is the picture that meme-image was generated from (courtesy of IMDb):

[image: Chet waves at Wyatt and Gary as they arrive]

Comment: This is the first major role I remember for Paxton, although his filmography goes 10 years further back.

Comment: Classic movie. Thankfully I had forgotten that image until now.

Comment: @RickHenderson - It really was a good visual representation of who Chet was on the inside.